# What does Alexa skill .getResponse() do?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I am learning js and to create simple Alexa skills.
I want to better understand the template code and I am studying the documentation at [https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/) but I cannot find an answer to this question.
The .getResponse() method is used in every handler template. It is also used in SessionEndedIntent handler, which means it cannot be a way to wait for user input. I tried googling but I can find no answer.
Can anyone explain what .getResponse() does, or point me to relevant documentation? Thanks.

```
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    // Any cleanup logic goes here.
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been pointed to the right answer, in case anyone else needs this:
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/f167aa0f-8abe-4602-b985-65118b3032ca/code-deep-dive-slots-and-session-attributes-in-the-ask-sdk-for-node-js

.getResponse() generates a JSON answer to communicate to Alexa:

> Generate the JSON response
>
> Finally, we add the `getResponse()` method to generate the JSON response back with our `speechOutput`.